# Can I move 0yum-cron from cron.daily to monthly?

Tags: centos, cron, yum

I installed the `yum-cron` package, configured too only check for updates and then mail me. But, doing this daily, seems a bit too much. I would like to do this monthly.

The file is located in `/etc/cron.daily/0yum-cron`, I want to move it to `/etc/cron.monthly/0yum-cron`. Can I do this, or is this a big no-no when using `yum-cron`?

Meaning by just doing this:

```
sudo mv /etc/cron.daily/0yum-cron /etc/cron.monthly/0yum-cron
```

Will this work?

Comment: If it's moved to monthly then how can we know which time and day of the month its going to run?

Comment: @MuppalaSaiCharan You may want to ask that as a new and separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to move it from daily to monthly run, you need to use `mv` and not `cp` as otherwise you would simply add a monthly run.
`sudo mv /etc/cron.daily/0yum-cron /etc/cron.monthly/0yum-cron` should do what you're asking for.

Comment: I started working before I had my coffee. I meant `mv`. If I `mv` it to `cron.monthly` will everything still work? This is my first time playing with `yum-cron`.

Comment: Yes, as `0yum-cron` is only used to call `yum-cron` at the frequency defined by when cron calls it with the yum-cron config file.